# how to build a function in order to process single iterable or two or more argument

Tags: python, function, optimization, coding-style

i have the following function example (average of a list of number):

```
def avg(obs):
    return (1. / len(obs)) * np.sum(obs)

avg([1,2,3,4,5])
3.0
```

I am interesting t understand how use a single iterable argument AND two or more argument as in in `max()`

```
max(1,2,3,4,5)
5
max([1,2,3,4,5])
5
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  It's usually better to just define a consistent API and require callers to pass in the argument(s) in the form you want.  It will make your code easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks BrenBarn I agree with you, It's a mine personal curiosity in order to understand programming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, you shouldn't unless you have a good reason; `min` and `max` do this because their binary form is so common, but e.g. `sum` only operates on iterables.

That said, the following does the trick.

```
from collections import Sized

def avg(*obs):
    if len(obs) == 1 and isinstance(obs[0], Sized):
        obs = obs[0]
    return (1. / len(obs)) * sum(obs)
```

(`Sized` is an abstract base class that generalizes lists, sets, dicts, tuples, NumPy arrays and various other containers. It makes sure `len` is defined.)

Comment: I can't seem to understand why does this work. What does the if check and obs assign do, shouldn't it check if `isinstance(obs[0], Sequence)`, isn't obs always a Sequence cause it uses the asterix thing?

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen: check whether there is only one argument of the right type, then reassign `obs` for the ensuing calculation.

Comment: Ye but isn't obs always a list of arguments?

Comment: Good to know I'm not stupid, I thought it's supposed to be that way cause of the upvotes, and couldn't understand why. Now it makes sense

Comment: Why are you using `Sized` instead of `Sequence` or `Iterable`?  In theory an object could be sized but not iterable (so `sum` would fail).  To be more general it would probably be better to check for iterable-ness and then iterate.

Comment: @BrenBarn: sets are not sequences, and iterables are not guaranteed to have a length. I admit that checking for both `Sized` and `Iterable` would be cleaner.